# Изменить цвет фона динамически созданного imageButtton

Tags: android, imageview

Есть `gridlayout`, в который динамически добавляются 88 `imageView`. Каждому `imageView` присваивается id с помощью метода `setId`. Как обратиться к `imageView`, к примеру, с id 10, чтобы изменить у него цвет фона?

```
for (int i=0; i<88; i++){
            imageId++;
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);           
            imageView.setId(imageId);
            gridlayout.addView(imageView);          

        }
```

Comment: `gridlayout.findViewById(10).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);`?

Comment: да я вчера и так пробовала, и через getId(), но в итоге всегда студия подчеркивает "10" с ошибкой "expected resourse of tipe id", как будто нельзя таким образом установить id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i=0; i<88; i++){
            imageId++;
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);           
            imageView.setTag(imageId);
            gridlayout.addView(imageView);          

}
```

///////////////

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewWithTag(10); // или другой тег
image.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
```

почему не используете gridView или recyclerview? Програмно создавать огромное количество елементов не сильно хорошее решение.

Comment: Спасибо, сработало) Я, честно говоря, пока еще не пришла к окончательному решению, что лучше использовать. Задача, на первый взгляд, банальна: есть картинка, отдельные области которой нужно сделать кликабельными. Первым в голову пришел вариант разбить картинку на составные части (картинки), все загрузить в gridlayout, ну и по тегу (как вы подсказали) найти нужную часть и сделать ее кликабельной. Если вы знаете какое-то более интересное решение и готовы им поделиться, я задам такой вопрос.

Comment: можно посмотреть на фото того что хотите получить? вы хотите резать 1 картинку на 88 частей и потом собирать их как исходную картинку, но уже с обработчиками нажатия?

Comment: картинку пока еще не рисовала, но вы все правильно поняли. Обработчики нажатия будут не у всех составных частей картинки. Я пробовала также другой вариант: загрузить картинку фоном layout, потом высчитать координаты "кликабельных областей" и потом с помощью touchlistener определять, коснулся ли пользователь нужной области или нет и обрабатывать это касание. Вариант оказался не из простых, т.к. картинок с кликабельными областями ожидается немало. Хотелось бы найти более простую реализацию идеи.

Comment: для себя я бы оставил одну целую картинку, но добавил для нее обработчик касаний. при касании получаю координаты точки и смотр попадает ли она в нужную мне область, если да то что-то сделать. вариант так же не очень красивый, но лучше чем постоянно резать картинки. Приверреализации обработчика касаний http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/08/detect-touch-on-imageview.html

Comment: Да, примерно так я пробовала (через обработчик касания), только у вас чуть другая реализация. Спасибо за мнение.

Comment: да и, кстати,  вариант ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewWithTag(10); не работает, нужно ImageView image = (ImageView) gridlayout.findViewWithTag(10);