# android - Как получить по ID программно созданную кнопку

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

В приложении динамически создается кнопка и ей задается ID:

```
butAss = new Button(this);
butAss.setId(++id);
```

Хочу на только что созданную кнопку добавить какое-либо действие, 
но не могу его зарегистрировать:

```
Button dayz;
dayz = (Button)findViewById(R.id.______);
```

Comment: речь идет именно о фрагменте (судя по тегам)?

Comment: Я тут тоже интересовалась этим вопросом. Это можно сделать, передав тег созданной кнопке: butAss = new Button(this);
butAss.setTag(++id); далее найти ее по нужному номеру тега, ответ здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/699450/Изменить-цвет-фона-динамически-созданного-imagebuttton/699453?noredirect=1#comment1037584_699453

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо по-другому сделать.

Так как вы добавляете динамически из кода `ID` для кнопки, то он не будет содеражвться в классе ресурсов, который генерируется при сборке приложения!

Вам надо запомнить тот `id`, который вы назначили:

```
Button butAss = new Button(this); //создаем кнопку
butAss.setId(100);                //назначаем id=100
somelayout.addView(butAss);       //добавляем в somelayout
```

Как получить доступ:

```
Button dayz;
dayz = (Button)somelayout.findViewById(100); // ищем элемент в somelayout с id=100
```

Comment: столкнулась сама с такой проблемой, таким образом, как вы предложили, Id не добавишь. Нашла ответ, как добавить id программно созданному view здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714297/android-view-setidint-id-programmatically-how-to-avoid-id-conflicts В ответе, набравшем бОльшее количество голосов, очень подробно расписано, "что и куда и почему"